# BoxWhiskerPlot - how to specify boxes position on the horizontal axis

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, charts

Let's say I have a folowing set of data:

- k = 1 : list of values
- k = 3 : list of values
- k = 10 : list of values

I know that to make a `BoxWhiskerChart` I have to give it a list of listen of these values as data and ks as labels.

How do I force the offset between the boxes for different ks to be proportional to the values of ks?

This is like combining `ListPlot` and `BoxWhiskerChart` - list plot gives appropriate position of boxes relative to the x-axis.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the `BoxWhiskerChart` doesn't label its x-axis coordinate, I decided to make use of the functionality that already exists in `ErrorListPlot`. The latter is part of the `"ErrorBarPlots"` package which has to be loaded explicitly.

First I generate the data, then I extract a list of coordinates for `ErrorListPlot`, then I specify a function that renders the "error bar" as a  `BoxWhiskerChart` for each data set individually. The scale has to be common to all plots, and that's achieved with a combination of fixed `PlotRange` and `AspectRatio -> Full` for the inset whisker plots.

```
data = {{1, RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 10]}, {3, 
    RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 10]}, {10, RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 10]}};

data = {{1, {7, -9, 5, 1, 3, 8, 10, 10, -3, 
     0}}, {3, {-8, -6, -6, 7, -8, -8, 2, -8, -2, -4}}, {10, {-9, -3, 
     9, 5, -1, 0, 9, 2, 3, -1}}};

dataValues = data[[All, 2]];
```

The original chart is here:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[dataValues]
```

[image: chart]

Now for the modifications to `ErrorListPlot`:

```
{min, max} = {Min[#], Max[#]} &@Flatten[dataValues]

(* ==> {-9, 10} *)

kValues = MapIndexed[Flatten[{#, min, #2}] &, data[[All, 1]]];

whiskers = Map[
   BoxWhiskerChart[#, Frame -> None, PlotRange -> {min, max}, 
     AspectRatio -> Full, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
     PlotRangeClipping -> False] &,
   dataValues];

Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

errorfunction[{x_, y_}, err_] := Inset[
  whiskers[[Last[Flatten[List @@ err]]]],
  {x, y}, {Center, Bottom}, Scaled[{.1, 1}]]

ErrorListPlot[kValues, ErrorBarFunction -> errorfunction, 
 PlotMarkers -> "", PlotRange -> {min, max}]
```

[image: error plot]

The tooltips of the original chart still work in this plot, too.

**Edit**

In response to the additional question about logarithmic x axis, we can work with the same data but can't use `ErrorListPlot`. So instead one could do this:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[
   List /@ kValues[[All, 1 ;; 2]], 
   PlotMarkers -> Map[{#, 1} &, whiskers], 
   PlotRange -> {min, max}] /. 
  Inset[i_, pos_, align_, scl_] :> 
   Inset[i, pos, {Center, Bottom}, Scaled[{.1, 1}]]
```

The idea is the same as above: *"inject"* the `BoxWhiskerChart` at the correct location by means of an `Inset`. The positioning can be taken care of by the plot function, but the *scaling* is not under my control in the plotting process. So I have to fix that by *post-processing* using the replacement `/.` with a rule  that looks for `Inset` in the finished plot and aligns its bottom with the plot point coordinate. The latter is always equal to the minimum data value (`min`), so that by setting `PlotRange` and using `Scaled[{.1, 1}]` for the fourth  `Inset` argument we get the same result as in `ErrorListPlot`, only with a logarithmic axis:

[image: log axis]

This last approach would of course also work with `ListPlot` and could therefore be a replacement for my my first solution.

A limitation of both approaches is that the vertical `PlotRange` must correspond exactly to the one in the `BoxWhiskerChart`, so that the scaling works properly by assuming the `Inset` should span `100%` of the vertical space. This means you can't add `PlotRangePadding` in the vertical direction. You can add it in the *horizontal* direction, though. Here is an illustration of an explicit horizontal `PlotRange` to keep the bars away from the edges:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[
  List /@ kValues[[All, 1 ;; 2]], 
  PlotMarkers -> Map[{#, 1} &, whiskers],
  AxesOrigin -> {.9, 0},
  PlotRange -> {{.9, 11}, {min, max}}] /. 
 Inset[i_, pos_, align_, scl_] :> 
  Inset[i, pos, {Center, Bottom}, Scaled[{.1, 1}]]
```

[image: plotrange example]

Comment: Awesome! Needed some tampering with origins and min and max (might be good to set to Min[{0,#}] but worked like a charm! You just saved me hours of work, thank you!

Comment: btw, any idea how to make x-axis logarithmic?

Comment: The error plot can only have a linear axis, unfortunately. I guess you could simply replace `k` by `Log[10, k]` in the labels for your data. But instead, I'll add a different approach that uses `ListLogLinearPlot`.

Comment: Nice! How about making both axes logarithmic?

Answer (score 9):

From [docs > BoxWhiskerChart >Scope > Data and Wrappers](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BoxWhiskerChart.html#):

> Nonreal data is taken to be missing and typically yields a gap in the box-and-whisker chart

So one can use the following approach:

```
salaries = ExampleData[{"Statistics", "UniversitySalaries"}, "DataElements"];
depts = {"Mathematics", "History", "English", "Chemistry", "Law", "Physics", "Statistics"};
data = Table[Cases[salaries, {d, _, salary_, "A"} :> salary], {d, depts}];
xrange = {1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 11, 12};
newdata = ConstantArray[Missing[], Max[xrange]];
newdata[[xrange]] = data;
xlabels = ConstantArray["", Max[xrange]];
xlabels[[xrange]] = xrange;

BoxWhiskerChart[newdata, ChartLabels -> Placed[xlabels, Axis],
  ChartStyle -> 10, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice trick (+1) (didn't know about `Missing`)

Comment: thank you @Jens. Actually, any _non-real_ data works the same way as `Missing[]`.

Comment: Nice, but much less universal. I assume it works only for natural values of ks which, in my case, wouldn't work. (ofcourse the question was simplified).

Comment: @JohnnyM - you could always rescale your k's by their least common multiple so that the x-axis is integers, and then just use the `FrameTicks` option to label them as you want.

Comment: @Verbeia for real numbers that might be a problem, but a neat idea. This could actualy come in handy, when you want to combine values that have numbered layers with values that don't. Which is what i have been trying to do for last few hours.

Comment: @JohnnyM - in that case, `Rationalize` is your friend. And maybe `Round`.

Comment: @kglr Hi, do you happen to know if there's a way to also include the table of stats per box such that they can be saved with the figure? As shown in your figure, I reckon you hovered the mouse over one WhiskerBox and the stats appeared, I am trying to show them all and save along with the figure, but haven't figured out how yet.

Comment: @CuriousBadger, maybe you can use something like `grid = Prepend[
   MapIndexed[Flatten[{#2, Quantile[#, {0, .25, .5, .75, 1}]}] &]@
    data, {"data set", "min", "25%", "median", "75%", "max"}];
Grid[grid, Alignment -> {{Center, {"."}}}, Dividers -> GrayLevel[0.3]]`?

Comment: @kglr thanks! Will give this a shot.

Answer (score 3):

At the request of one user I included a BoxWhisherDraw statement in the latest release of Presentations (which I sell for $50.). This essentially draws a chart centered at zero and then you can easily Scale/Rotate/Translate it to wherever you wish. So here is a solution to your problem using `BoxWiskerDraw`:

```
<<Presentations`

data[1] = Array[RandomReal[{0, 1}] &, 10];
data[3] = Array[1 + RandomReal[{0, 3}] &, 10];
data[10] = Array[5 + RandomReal[{0, 10}] &, 10];


xticks = CustomTicks[Identity, databased[{1, 3, 10}]];
Draw2D[
 {({BoxWhiskerDraw[data[#],
         ChartStyle -> 
          Directive[FaceForm[Opacity[0.2, Blue]], EdgeForm[Black], 
           Thin]],
        CirclePoint[{0, #}, 3, Black, White] & /@ data[#]} // 
       ScaleOp[{3, 1}, {0, 0}] // TranslateOp[{#, 0}]) & /@ {1, 3, 
    10}},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {xticks, 
    xticks // NoTickLabels}},
 PlotLabel -> Style["Custom BoxWhisker Chart", 13, Bold],
 ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I also used CirclePoint to mark the data points for each data set and I used CustomTicks to put ticks at just the k values.

**Addition**

The poster asked if a log x axis could be used. Yes, very simple. In the above we simply add a `Log10` as the scaling function in `CustomTicks` and to the `TranslateOp` command. And we change the width scaling in `ScaleOp`.

```
xticks = CustomTicks[Log10, databased[{1, 3, 10}]];
Draw2D[
 {({BoxWhiskerDraw[data[#],
         ChartStyle -> 
          Directive[FaceForm[Opacity[0.2, Blue]], EdgeForm[Black], 
           Thin]],
        CirclePoint[{0, #}, 3, Black, White] & /@ data[#]} // 
       ScaleOp[{1/2, 1}, {0, 0}] // 
      TranslateOp[{Log10[#], 0}]) & /@ ({1, 3, 10})},
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 PlotRange -> {{-0.3, 1.3}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {xticks, 
    xticks // NoTickLabels}},
 PlotLabel -> Style["Custom BoxWhisker Chart", 13, Bold],
 ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Using a custom `ChartElementFunction` that translates the graphics primitives based on specified `x` values passed as metadata:

```
ClearAll[ceF]
ceF[func_: "GlassBoxWhisker"][delta_] := 
 ChartElementData[func][{#3[[1]] + {-delta, delta}, #[[2]]}, ##2] &

salaries = ExampleData[{"Statistics", "UniversitySalaries"}, "DataElements"];
depts = {"Mathematics", "History", "English", "Chemistry", "Law", 
   "Physics", "Statistics"};
data = Table[Cases[salaries, {d, _, salary_, "A"} :> salary], {d, depts}];

SeedRandom[3]
xvalues = Sort@RandomReal[100, Length@data];
delta = 2 Min[Differences[xvalues]]/5;

Show[BoxWhiskerChart[Thread[data -> xvalues], ChartStyle -> 10, 
  ImageSize -> 500, ChartElementFunction -> (ceF[][delta]), ChartLegends -> depts], 
 ListLinePlot[Transpose[{xvalues, Median /@ data}], PlotStyle -> Thick], 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, 
   {{#, Rotate[Style[#, 14, Bold, "Panel"], 90 Degree]} & /@ 
     xvalues, {#, ""} & /@ xvalues}}, 
 ImagePadding -> {{40, 10}, {70, 10}}]
```

[image]