# BoxWhiskerChart with logarithmic axes

Tags: probability-or-statistics, plotting

I would like to make a following chart

[image: BoxWhiskerChart with log y-axis]

Ideally I would also like to control the boxes position on a logarithmic x-axis.

Some inspiration how to do the latter may be found in the answer to my other question:
[How to controll position on the x-axis of a boxWhiskerChart](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18691/boxwhiskerplot-how-to-specify-boxes-position-on-the-horizontal-axis)

TIA:)

Comment: Seems like you'll have to build such a plot from scratch, I see no easy way to use the existing functionality. This means working directly with `Graphics` primitives to construct the display.

Comment: @Jens crap. How come gnuplot has it and mathematica don't.

Comment: @Jens there is a way: the option `ScalingFunctions`. I've added an answer detailing how it works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Buried in the Details section of the documentation for [`BoxWhiskerChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BoxWhiskerChart.html) is a reference to an option called [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) which when set "the data coordinate is scaled using s." So, first some data:

```
data = RandomVariate[RayleighDistribution[RandomInteger[500]], {8, 50}];
```

without the scaling functions:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Outliers", ChartStyle -> 56]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and with `ScalingFunctions` set to "Log":

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Outliers", ChartStyle -> 56, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You might need a custom list of `FrameTicks` to get the desired formatting. Some ideas to get you started can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3739/8), [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5278/8) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5369/8).

Comment: Great find (+1)!

Comment: @Jens thanks. I've been staring at these functions for a bit now, and sometimes interesting things appear.

Comment: Exacly what I was looking for! Awesome answer!

Comment: This solution (ScalingFunctions) unfortunately doesn't work with the numbers less than 1((

Comment: @MaxSakharov I see the issue in v9.0.1, but it appears to work correctly in the internal betas. So, if you need the feature, I would advise upgrading when the next version comes out.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using the commercial Presentations package (which I develop).

```
<<Presentations`
```

Here are some data sets defined by their Log10 values.

```
data[1] = Array[RandomReal[{0, 1}] &, 10];
data[2] = Array[RandomReal[{0, 1.5}] &, 10];
data[3] = Array[RandomReal[{-1, 1}] &, 10];
data[4] = Array[RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}] &, 10];
data[5] = Array[RandomReal[{-0.5, 1}] &, 10];
```

Here is the BoxWhisker plot code.

```
xticks = CustomTicks[Identity, 
   databased[{{1, "CMEE"}, {2, "CUL"}, {3, "SR"}, {4, "DR"}, {5, 
      "AC"}}]];
yticks = CustomTicks[
   Log10, {-1, 2, {1, 2, 5} // N, {3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9}}];
Draw2D[
 {{Dotted, Line[{{0, Log10[1]}, {6, Log10[1]}}]},
  ({BoxWhiskerDraw[data[#],
         ChartStyle -> 
          Directive[FaceForm[Opacity[0.2, Blue]], EdgeForm[Black], 
           Thin]],
        CirclePoint[{0, #}, 3, Black, White] & /@ data[#]} // 
       ScaleOp[{1, 1}, {0, 0}] // TranslateOp[{#, 0}]) & /@ Range[5]},
 AspectRatio -> 0.8,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{yticks, yticks // NoTickLabels}, {xticks, 
    xticks // NoTickLabels}},
 PlotLabel -> Style["BoxWhisker Chart with Log Y Scale", 13, Bold],
 ImageSize -> 400]
```

And here is the plot:

[image: Mathematica graphics]