# BoxWhiskerChart with logarithmic axes 2

Tags: version-9, logarithmic-scale, charts

I actually already found my answer on the question, however it is not working. 
see [BoxWhiskerChart with logarithmic axes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18810/boxwhiskerchart-with-logarithmic-axes)

I want to create a boxwiskerchart with a logaritmic axes. But when I try `ScalingFunctions` with "Log" I do not get the results I am suppose to get. Sometimes it does not work at all. And sometimes I get the wiskers upside down. What am I doing wrong?

```
data = RandomVariate[RayleighDistribution[RandomInteger[500]], {8, 50}];
BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Outliers", ChartStyle -> 56]
```

[image]

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Outliers", ChartStyle -> 56, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]

Also using Log10 does not work

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Outliers", ChartStyle -> 56, ScalingFunctions -> "Log10"]
```

[image]

Comment: Seems to be an issue of Mma v9. No such problems in Mma v10.

Comment: I am using mathematica 9.0. So it is not possible to do use the 'ScalingFunctions' on a box plot in this version?

Comment: Are there other options to do it in version 9.0?

Comment: You can do it in the [WolframProgrammingCloud](http://www.wolframcloud.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that will work in version 9, although it requires you to install the [`CustomTicks`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kmisiunas/mathematica-customticks/master/CustomTicks.m) package.  Here is a `BoxWhiskerChart` using the normal linear scaling:

```
SeedRandom[420];
data = RandomVariate[
   RayleighDistribution[RandomInteger[500]], {8, 50}];
bwc = BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Outliers", ChartStyle -> 56]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the log-scaled chart you get from version 10,

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Outliers", ChartStyle -> 56, 
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log10"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And here is the bootstrapped log-scale chart from version 9:

```
<< CustomTicks`
BoxWhiskerChart[Log10@data, "Outliers", ChartStyle -> 56, 
 FrameTicks -> {{LogTicks[10, 1, 4], 
    StripTickLabels[LogTicks[10, 1, 4]]}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]